# Storing large amounts of text in js object vs xml or json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I'm making a RPG now and storing dialog text in a JS object, like so:

```
var dialog = {

  quests : {
     Lee : {
        "1 - Introductions" :
        {
            "chinese" :
            [
                "Hi, I'm Lee.",
                "I checked your information, I think we can use you...",
```

Then accessing it as such:

```
game.data.NPCdialog = dialog.quests[game.data.currNPC][currTask]["chinese"][0];
```

I asked how to use require.js to dynamically load js files because I want to store several npc_dialog files per level and load them as needed. I asked that here:

[using requireJS to dynamically load js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531804/using-requirejs-to-dynamically-load-js-files/23539199?noredirect=1#23539199)

Both replyers mentions using XML or JSON to store the dialog text rather than inside a JS object, and loading it with AJAX.

Why is storing the text in that format better?

Comment: which format are you pointing at with "that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice thing about storing it in smaller json objects and loading them with AJAX is the site will use less resources in the browser and you can just load the required data when needed. If the data isn't too large then having it all loaded in a javascript object would provide faster access.

One thing to note is that your javascript object could have script in it and not just data where if you used JSON or XML files they would be limited to just data.

Answer (score 3):

Storing it as JSON or XML isn't better or worse. It's just more easy to load and use in your scenario. It's a simpler solution.